# I need to run many apache2.0 servers on different docker container and give each one port number

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am quite new to Docker and I need to run 8 apache2.0 servers on different docker containers and give each container a port number using compose. 
I found apache2.0 image and I created a container through this command:

```
docker create -t -i lamsley/apache2.0
```

How can I create many webservers and give each one a port number in way I can access it through the internet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just Docker you can run:

```
docker run --name server1 -d -p 8000:80 lamsley/apache2.0
docker run --name server2 -d -p 8001:80 lamsley/apache2.0
...
```

It's easier with Docker Compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
  httpd1:
    image: lamsley/apache2.0
    container_name: httpd1
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
  httpd2:
    image: lamsley/apache2.0
    container_name: httpd1
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
   ...
```

But I strongly suggest you learn Docker first because these snippets are simplistic.  You need to know about volumes to pass the content to be served, etc.  Why use lamsley/apache2.0 when you can use the official `httpd` image?  You can build your own custom image.  The possibilities are endless and it is fun.

To learn about Docker Compose:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

To learn about volumes:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/